# alternatives for excessive for() looping in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, sorting, loops

**Situation**

I'm currently writing a javascript widget that displays a random quote into a html element. the quotes are stored in a javascript array as well as how many times they've been displayed into the html element. A quote to be displayed cannot be the same quote as was previously displayed. Furthermore the chance for a quote to be selected is based on it's previous occurences in the html element. ( less occurrences should result in a higher chance compared to the other quotes to be selected for display.

**Current solution**

I've currently made it work ( with my severely lacking javascript knowledge ) by using a lot of looping through various arrays. while this currently works ( !! ) I find this solution rather expensive for what I want to achieve.

**What I'm looking for**

- *Alternative methods of removing an array element from an array*, currently looping through the entire array to find the element I want removed and copy all other elements into a new array
- Alternative method of calculating and selecting a element from an array based on it's occurence
- Anything else you notice I should / could do different while still enforcing the stated business rules under **Situation**

**The Code**

```
var quoteElement = $("div#Quotes > q"),
    quotes = [[" AAAAAAAAAAAA ", 1],
              [" BBBBBBBBBBBB ", 1],
              [" CCCCCCCCCCCC ", 1],
              [" DDDDDDDDDDDD ", 1]],
    fadeTimer = 600,
    displayNewQuote = function () {

                        var currentQuote = quoteElement.text();
                        var eligibleQuotes = new Array();
                        var exclusionFound = false;
                        for (var i = 0; i < quotes.length; i++) {
                            var iteratedQuote = quotes[i];
                            if (exclusionFound === false) {
                                if (currentQuote == iteratedQuote[0].toString())
                                    exclusionFound = true;
                                else
                                    eligibleQuotes.push(iteratedQuote);
                            } else
                                eligibleQuotes.push(iteratedQuote);
                        }
                        eligibleQuotes.sort( function (current, next) {
                            return current[1] - next[1];
                        } );

                        var calculatePoint = eligibleQuotes[0][1];
                        var occurenceRelation = new Array();
                        var relationSum = 0;
                        for (var i = 0; i < eligibleQuotes.length; i++) {
                            if (i == 0)
                                occurenceRelation[i] = 1 / ((calculatePoint / calculatePoint) + (calculatePoint / eligibleQuotes[i+1][1]));
                            else
                                occurenceRelation[i] = occurenceRelation[0] * (calculatePoint / eligibleQuotes[i][1]);
                            relationSum = relationSum + (occurenceRelation[i] * 100);
                        }

                        var generatedNumber = Math.floor(relationSum * Math.random());
                        var newQuote;
                        for (var i = 0; i < occurenceRelation.length; i++) {
                            if (occurenceRelation[i] <= generatedNumber) {
                                newQuote = eligibleQuotes[i][0].toString();
                                i = occurenceRelation.length;
                            }
                        }

                        for (var i = 0; i < quotes.length; i++) {
                            var iteratedQuote = quotes[i][0].toString();
                            if (iteratedQuote == newQuote) {
                                quotes[i][1]++;
                                i = quotes.length;
                            }
                        }

                        quoteElement.stop(true, true)
                                    .fadeOut(fadeTimer);
                        setTimeout( function () {
                            quoteElement.html(newQuote)
                                        .fadeIn(fadeTimer);
                        }, fadeTimer);

                    } 

if (quotes.length > 1) 
    setInterval(displayNewQuote, 10000);
```

**Alternatives considered**

- Always chose the array element with the lowest occurence.

  *Decided against this as this would / could possibly reveal a too obvious pattern in the animation*
- combine several for loops to reduce the workload

  *Decided against this as this would make the code to esoteric, I'd probably wouldn't understand the code anymore next week*

**jsFiddle reference**

http://jsfiddle.net/P5rk3/

### Update

Rewrote my function with the techniques mentioned, while I fear that these techniques still loop through the entire array to find it's requirements, at least my code looks cleaner : )

References used after reading the answers here:

- http://www.tutorialspoint.com/javascript/array_map.htm
- http://www.tutorialspoint.com/javascript/array_filter.htm
- http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.each/

Comment: The accepted answer nails it pretty good. Also, I would suggest the ["without" function, from underscore.js](http://underscorejs.org/#without). Actually, underscore.js will help you with several Array problems.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suggest array functions that are mostly supported (and easily added if not):

```
[].splice(index, howManyToDelete); // you can alternatively add extra parameters to slot into the place of deletion
[].indexOf(elementToSearchFor);
[].filter(function(){});
```

Other useful functions include `forEach` and `map`.

I agree that combining all the work into one giant loop is ugly (and not always possible), and you gain little by doing it, so readability is definitely the winner. Although you shouldn't need too many loops with these array functions.

Comment: Accepted this answer, it was the one that eventually led me towards a 'better' solution. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

The answer that you want:

Create an integer array that stores the number of uses of every quote. Also, a global variable `Tot` with the total number of quotes already used (i.e., the sum of that integer array). Find also `Mean`, as `Tot / number of quotes`.

Chose a random number between 0 and `Tot - 1`.

For each quote, add `Mean * 2 - the number of uses`(*1). When you get that that value has exceeded the random number generated, select that quote.

In case that quote is the one currently displayed, either select the next or the previous quote or just repeat the process.

The real answer:

Use a random quote, at the very maximum repeat if the quote is duplicated. The data usages are going to be lost when the user reloads/leaves the page. And, no matter how cleverly have you chosen them, most users do not care.

(*1) Check for limits, i.e. that the first or last quota will be eligible with this formula.

Comment: In regards to the **that I want**: would that method not horribly fail while 0 / 1 quotes have been displayed before the interval, tot(0 / 1) - 1 would resolve to -1 / 0. in regards to the **real answer** yes, I might have gone too far with this, but I got into the mindset of really wanting to nail this ( do it as perfect as possible )  :)

Answer (score 1):

> *Alternative methods of removing an array element from an array*

With ES5's [`Array.filter()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) method:

```
Array.prototype.without = function(v) {
    return this.filter(function(x) {
        return v !== x;
    });
};
```

given an array `a`, `a.without(v)` will return a copy of `a` without the element `v` in it.

> *less occurrences should result in a higher chance compared to the other quotes to be selected for display*

You shouldn't mess with chance - as my mathematician other-half says, "chance doesn't have a memory".

What you're suggesting is akin to the idea that numbers in the lottery that haven't come up yet must be "overdue" and therefore more likely to appear.  It simply isn't true.

Comment: _independent_ experiments do not have memory ;-)

Comment: In regards to your latest quote. I merely 'created' this rule to reduce the odds of constantly looking at quotes 1 to 3 while quote 4 never appeared on your screen. While this could still happen in the current situation, it's less likely. So in my case, it is true that those quotes are overdue.

Comment: @marcusklass true - but each call to `random()` is kind of like an independent experiment - just as each throw of a dice or toss of a coin is.

Answer (score 0):

You can write functions that explicitly define what you're trying to do with the loop.

Your first loop is a *filter*.
Your second loop is a map + some side effect.
I don't know about the other loops, they're weird :P

A filter is something like:

```
function filter(array, condition) {
    var i = 0, new_array = [];
    for (; i < array.length; i += 1) {
        if (condition(array[i], i)) {
            new_array.push(array[i]);
        }
    }
    return new_array;
}

var numbers = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9];
var even_numbers = filter(numbers, function (number, index) {
    return number % 2 === 0;
});
alert(even_numbers); // [2,4,6,8]
```

You **can't** avoid the loop, but you can add more **semantics** to the code by making a function that explains what you're doing.

Comment: ES5 has `Array.filter()` built in

Comment: True, but there are other loop operations that are not.

Answer (score 0):

If, for some reason, you are not comfortable with `splice` or `filter` methods, there is a nice (outdated, but still working) method by John Resig: http://ejohn.org/blog/javascript-array-remove/